# Celery - How to get IDs of tasks not yet reserved, active or finished?

Tags: celery

Is there a way to get the ID of tasks that have been sent to the RabbitMQ virtual host but haven't been reserved by a Celery instance yet (i.e. the message is still on the celery queue)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It involves reading messages from the RabbitMQ 'celery' queue and then re-queuing them. Here is a tool I wrote which does this (among other things): https://github.com/brendanmaguire/Celery-Tasks-Ctl

Hopefully it can be useful to someone else if they find themselves in a similar situation.